# Symfony -undefined method named "render" of class

Tags: symfony

im new to symfony framework. it raises render error. i tried all suggestions

```
@App/default/index.html.twig
AppBundle:default:index.html.twig
default/index.html.twig
```

**routing.yml**

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

lucky_number:
    path:     /lucky/number/{count}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Lucky:number }
```

**LuckyController.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number/{count}")
     */
    public function numberAction($count)
    {
        $number = rand(0, 100);
        $html = $this->render('@App/default/index.html.twig','number'=>$number);
        //$html = $this->container->get('templating')->render('AppBundle:default:index.html.twig',array('number' => $number));
        //$html = $this->container->get('templating')->render('default/index.html.twig',array('number' => $number));
        return new Response($html);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "render" of class
>   "AppBundle\Controller\LuckyController".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forgot to extend your controller class with the symfony controller.

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LuckyController extends Controller // <-- HERE
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number/{count}")
     */
    public function numberAction($count)
    {
        $number = rand(0, 100);
        return $this->render('AppBundle:default:index.html.twig',array('number' => $number));
    }
}
```